# Unable to change Frame colour Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I am trying to change colour of **frame** but unable to change it to black
Please tell the error

```
from tkinter import * ;
root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root);
frame.configure(background='black')
logo=Label(frame,text="gogo",fg="green");
logo.pack();
frame.pack();

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* changing the color. You just can't see it because the frame shrunk to fit the label.

If you want the frame to fill the window, you need to use some options to `pack`:

```
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: I wanted to upvote ur ans but can't since I have less reputation.Plz upvote my question ,I will upvote ur ans

Comment: @zzz123 up voting a question is meant to be used when a good question is asked. Your question is not really a good question as it has been ask many many times.

Comment: What does expand do ?

Comment: @zzz123 It tells tkinter to let the widget fill any extra space in the master.

Comment: @zzz123: I can't upvote your question. It shows no signs of you doing any research before asking the question, which makes it a low quality question.